# Calling Nexus API to return all artifacts for a repo

Tags: api, nexus

I'm trying to run a nexus search to return all of the artifacts for a specific repo.  I know there are ways of doing this from the file system but I need to be able to do it from the an api call. 
When I try to do something like: http://{host}/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r={repo-name} I get a "400 - Bad Request The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax".

I also tried to include the p for package search using WAR, war, JAR and jar but it returned nothing as well but got the same 400 error.  I must be missing things but I can't figure out what it is.

I have everything else working to use the data as long as I can get it out from the API so I don't want to get it in a different format so that I have to rework the rest of my code.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [lucene search API](http://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/index.html). Something like:

```
http://myhost:8081/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?repositoryId=myrepo&q=jar
```